# SQL Truncation Issue Converting VARCHAR to VARBINARY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, varchar, varbinary

I have a fairly simple insert from a csv file into a temp table into a table with an encrypted column.

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(number varchar(32) NOT NULL
, user_varchar1 varchar(65) NOT NULL
, account varchar(32) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE #temp1
(number varchar(32) NOT NULL
, user_varchar1 varchar(65) NOT NULL
, account varchar(32) NOT NULL)


OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SKey                    
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE CERTCERT 
--Flat File Insert
BULK INSERT #temp1 
FROM '\\Server\Data\filename.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
, FIRSTROW =2
, ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);

INSERT INTO table1
(number, user_varchar1, account_encrypted)
SELECT user_varchar1, number
, ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('SKey'),(CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), account)))
FROM #temp1

--SELECT * FROM #esa_import_ach
DROP TABLE #temp1
SELECT * FROM table1

CLOSE MASTER KEY
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SKey;
```

The error I receive is

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 11, Line 40
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

Now if I allow `NULLS` into table1, it fills with `NULLS`, obviously.  If I omit the account_encrypted column altogether, the script works.

If I use

```
INSERT INTO table1 (number, user_varchar1, account) 
VALUES ('175395', '87450018RS', ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('SKey'), (CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), account)))
```

there's no problem.

So, is there something wrong with the way I'm executing the `BULK INSERT`, is it my declaration of the data types or is it the source file itself.

The source file looks like this (just one row):

```
emp_id, number, account
175395, 87450018RS,GRDI27562**CRLF**
```

Thanks and I'm hoping this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your account column is defined as varchar(32).

[ENCRYPTBYKEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174361.aspx) returns a result with a max size of 8000.  That just won't fit in your column.  Either expand the column, or cast the result to a smaller size to fit it inside the column.  Right now it just won't fit.

Comment: I can use `VARCHAR(MAX)` and it doesn't change the result.  Why would it work if I user `INSERT INTO` but not in a `BULK INSERT`?